# SQL Database in android not updating

Tags: android, database

I take input in an edittext, that is in a popup window. On dismiss of that popup, the string in edittext should be updated in db at required postion.

Popup Window code:

```
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popl,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pop));
                    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 700 * (metrics.widthPixels/1080) , 300 * (metrics.heightPixels/1080) , true);
                    int coord[]= new int[2];
                    v.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
                    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent)));
                    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                    pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, coord[0] + 50 ,coord[1]+100);

                    Button del = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.del);
                    Button viewImage = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.view);
                    final EditText notes = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.note);
                    notes.setText(data[6]);
                    notedata = data[6];

                    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            SQLiteDatabase db = dBcontract.getWritableDatabase();
                            if ((thisimageuri!=null)&&(thisimageuri.toString().charAt(0)!='a'))
                                deleteimage(thisimageuri);
                            Log.d("delete operaiton",String.valueOf(db.delete(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.tableName,eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnID+" = "+data[4],null)));
                            recreate();                                                         //add option to delete files as well
                        }
                    });

                    viewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (thisimageuri!=null)
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),showPic.class);
                                intent.putExtra("photo uri",thisimageuri);
                                notedata = notes.getText().toString();
                                pw.dismiss();
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    pw.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss() {
                            notedata = notes.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("popop window", "onDismiss: " + notedata);
                            interact.savenote(data[4],notedata);
                        }
                    });


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Method to save in database:

```
 public void savenote(String id , String note)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = dBcontract.getWritableDatabase();

    values.put(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnnotes,note);
    db.update(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.tableName,values,"id=?",new String[]{id});
    Log.d("Interact","add note complete " + note);

}
```

The code works correctly,i.e note is saved correctly in db, when i click on view image but not when I click outside of popup to dismiss it.

Log:

```
04-14 00:12:24.569 9517-9517/lcukerd.com.stufflist D/popop window: onDismiss: Yu
04-14 00:12:24.569 9517-9517/lcukerd.com.stufflist D/Interact: add note complete Yu
```

Help me spot the issue. This is eating my brain.

EDIT 1:
data[4] is the id of entry in db to be updated.
data[6] is the old value of "note" as saved in db.

Comment: The [update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update\\(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[]\\)) method returns an integer - showing the number of rows affected by the query. What does this return? If no rows are affected, your query is incorect.

Comment: It returns 1 @MattClark

Comment: what is data[4] and data[6]

Comment: @Elsunhoty i edited now

Comment: are you using constran data ?
I mean , it`s appear that every time you update same column ?

Comment: try to Fetch the data with Id data[4]?

Comment: You are genius @Elsunhoty . I am not using constant data but i am not updating frequently enough (only at start of activity) thats why it worked after clicking on view image(it has recreate()) and not otherwise.